# Pointer reference through function call C++

Tags: c++

I got an example function by the form:

```
vector<int> function(var&){...}
```

The variable is defined in another .cpp file (if relevant), and I assume the 'var&' is needed so the original value gets overwritten and no copy is made. My problem arises when trying to use that variable. More specifically what I would like to do is use a function specified for that class. (e.g. var.func() )

What i tried (pseudo language):

```
vector<int> function(var& a){
    a.func;
}
```

This does not work since i get an error. "invalid use of incomplete type 'class var'". It must have something to do with defining 'a'.

```
vector<int> function(var a){
    a.func;
}
```

When changing the input 'var&' to 'var' like above i get the error "'a' has incomplete type".

It also notes "forward declaration of 'class var'" in both cases above.

```
vector<int> function(var&){
    ~some random code without defining a 'var&'~ 
}
```

This runs perfectly.

In another .cpp file i can just use

```
var a; 
a.func;
```

I included the header file of the .cpp file (which also declared var a). Still thesame errors appear.

What kind of workaround can I use? Since the "vector function(var&){...}" is given I don't think I'm supposed to change the input type.

Comment: You need to `#include` the .h file that defines `var` in the .cpp file.

Comment: Your notes after the code are unclear. If something works and something else doesn't, and you want to know why, then post the two versions of code. If the two versions of code generate different errors, and you want to know why, then post the two versions of code, and also post both errors. You can [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: To clarify I edited my post, hope it makes some sense.

Comment: If all the compiler knows is that `var` is some class (via the forward declaration), how can it verify that `a.func` is valid?

Comment: Since I also included the header file that defined `a.func`. `a.func` is actually a really simple item, as the `.func` is just an array linked to `var a`.

Comment: Maybe you have a circular include. A [mcve] would allow for an answer that clearly demonstrates that the problem is fixed.

Comment: Why are you naming your type `var`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However this does not work since i get an error. "invalid use of incomplete type 'class var'". It must have something to do with defining 'a'.

No, it isn't so much something to do with defining `a` rather than defining `var`. `var` must be defined before that function but it wasn't.

> What kind of workaround can I use?

Solution is simple: Include the definition of `var` before the definition of `function`:

```
struct var {
   int func;
};
vector<int> function(var& a){
    a.func;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is this still necessary if I include a header file (as var is actually a whole class)?

Comment: @Christoph the definition must be there in some way or another. Including a file that defines it is OK.